# Statistical technique for distinguishing between artefacts and no artefacts

Tags: statistics, numerical-algorithms, image-processing

I would like to know how to create an algorithm from the table below in order to distinguish between data that has artefacts and data that does not.

I'm trying to leverage video attributes like intensity, brightness, and colour to identify flickering or glitchy sections in a video using the data below, which was gathered from several web videos. After calculating all the statistics, a find peak and valley approach is used to compare videos with artefacts against ones without them.

However, based on my observations of false positives in my research, it appears that categorization is trivial and bimodal.

Refer to column "c" for further information. If a Numpks has a number, it contains an artefact; otherwise, it does not. To create a marker to separate artefact from no artefact data, which does not appear to be avoidable at this time because none of the markers fit into the concept of artefact to no artefact separation, I would like to have a clear threshold from the table.

A mathematical method or model that fits the data in the table below would be ideal so that I can statistically separate artefact from no artefact.

Algorithm for Identifying Artefacts in Video Data

• Utilizes video attributes like intensity, brightness, and color to identify flickering or glitchy sections.

• Uses find peak and valley approach to compare videos with artefacts against those without.

• Observations suggest categorization is trivial and bimodal.

• Numpks with a number indicates an artefact.

• Needs a clear threshold to separate artefact from no artefact data.

• Need Help: A mathematical method or model that fits the table would be ideal for statistical separation.

https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/y1zd0os2ts09frwbryd0v/metric_analysis.xlsx?rlkey=w3ep21p2m0yqu0kq9q3gkhhex&dl=0

Thank you!!

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SE.SP! I’ve closed your question for several reasons: first, we don’t allow questions asking for code as one of our first line, site-specific close reasons. Second, the question doesn’t really explain what an artifact is and what an artifact isn’t. One person’s feast is another’s poison. Third, please make the data available either here or on a binary sharing site (Dropbox, Google docs, etc) so we can see what you mean. 

Please edit your question to address these issues and ping me and I can reopen if they’re addressed.

Comment: This being said: this seems trivial. Take a look at the "std-dev", "min" and "max" columns. There are highly bi-modal and the modality is highly correlated.

Comment: Hi Peter K,
please make the data available either here or on a binary sharing site (Dropbox, Google docs, etc) so we can see what you mean ?

I attempted to enter the excel data here, but I am not able to. Could you please provide me with the procedures to upload the data?

Comment: *” If a Numpks has a number, it contains an artefact; otherwise, it does not.”*… ok so what more do you want? Your question is very confusing. You say you need a method to identify “artefact vs no-artefact data” but here you say you already **have** it, specified by the presence of a number higher than $0$ in the Numpks column…

Comment: Aids in distinguishing artefacts from non-artifacts when using the Numpeak Indicator. I can't use Numpeak since I know which films contain artefacts and which do not.

We must utilise other parameters such as std, min, max, mean, rms, mode, and so on to decide between artefacts and no artefacts,

Comment: Peter K, Do you feel, the current stated problem is not good enough for answer ?